# ClearLinux on Openstack

Tags: linux, openstack, disk-image

I'm having trouble getting ClearLinux to work on OpenStack.

From their [download source](https://download.clearlinux.org/image/), based on their sites download page & documentation, I've tried clear-29690-cloud.img, clear-29690-cloud-native.img, clear-29690-live-server.img, and clear-29690-live-server.iso after running it through conversion. I can't tell if this is something specific with clearlinux or not.

[Their documentation](https://clearlinux.org/documentation/clear-linux/guides/maintenance/image-types) states the one for OpenStack is the cloud-img file.

We reference [this documentation](https://docs.openstack.org/image-guide/convert-images.html) on how to convert an image to a raw format by the documentation of the internal cluster, but even after converting I'm still running into either "Booting from Hard Drive" or "Boot failed: not a bootable disk - No bootable device".

After trying these images, I run `openstack image create --private --disk-format raw --container-format bare` and have passed the images themselves and the qcow2 images over. I would think the images would be in their proper formats and that I may be doing the step of converting them to qcow2 types needlessly, but in all scenarios nothing works and I'm having the *worst* of luck here. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:

[Rancher releases as qcow2](https://rancher.com/docs/os/v1.2/en/running-rancheros/cloud/openstack/). just noticed I was also converting from what was given to qcow2 for half of my attempts. Maybe that is the key. Is it a standard to release in qcow2 for openstack images? Testing this now.

Also lets be adults and not downvote without comment here.

Edit 2:
TIL (Tonight(at 3am) I learned)

```
qemu-img convert -f qcow2 -O raw clear-29690-cloud.img clear-29690-cloud.raw
```

I was not only doing the conversion backward but qcow2 is the format given by Clear Linux's OpenStack image and maybe the common one for OpenStack in general. Fun venture. Thanks [Rancher](https://rancher.com/docs/os/v1.2/en/running-rancheros/cloud/openstack/)!

Edit 3: Spoke too soon. RancherOS works. Clear Linux still stalls at "Booting form harddisk"

```
+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                           --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                           ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Field            | Value                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                           --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                           ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| checksum         | ada1f029ffbaee41f10b4fc2422d9f38                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    |
| container_format | bare                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                |
| created_at       | 2019-05-31T08:09:06Z                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                |
| disk_format      | raw                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 |
| file             | /v2/images/33dc7258-27ff-4807-b552-a57a823e1fd7/file                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                |
| id               | 33dc7258-27ff-4807-b552-a57a823e1fd7                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                |
| min_disk         | 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   |
| min_ram          | 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   |
| name             | clear-29690-cloud-raw-actual                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        |
| owner            | 61af61cc80b04e14a185f5a08e763d3c                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    |
| properties       | direct_url='rbd://bd0b115f-4871-4bc0-a5e8-0207e6e69f18/images/33dc7258-27ff-4807-b552-a57a823e1fd7/snap', locations='[{u'url': u'rbd://bd0b115f                                                                                                           -4871-4bc0-a5e8-0207e6e69f18/images/33dc7258-27ff-4807-b552-a57a823e1fd7/snap', u'metadata': {}}]', os_hash_algo='sha512', os_hash_value='44fb841206b98e1505524e829f                                                                                                           4189bf464aac1659686dc7fdb8fd40135a36bad41b1859c124e76ce375f24c3dfde3718ee20dcf7681a75ed61d86846d6f3cc5', os_hidden='False' |
| protected        | False                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
| schema           | /v2/schemas/image                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   |
| size             | 907018240                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
| status           | active                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
| tags             |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
| updated_at       | 2019-05-31T08:09:53Z                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                |
| virtual_size     | None                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                |
| visibility       | private                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             |
+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                           --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                           ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

[From their team's response](https://community.clearlinux.org/t/clearlinux-on-openstack/615/2?u=quantomworks), the images provided were using UEFI. Our OpenStack glance service currently does not support this. For anyone seeing this with control over their stack, [here is how to enable it](https://docs.openstack.org/glance/pike/admin/troubleshooting.html#launch-instances-with-uefi).